# iOS simulator issue in an empty application

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I have an issue with my very first attempt at Xcode 5.1.1. After I created a new empty application on the startup menu I clicked file/new/file/Storyboard and I created a new storyboard that I chose as the main storyboard in the deployment info, I added a View Controller and a Text Field and then I compiled through the run button on the top left and the iOS simulator still contains nothing.

Comment: check - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 it should only have return YES;

Comment: Xcode asks when you set up the project whether you want to use a storyboard. If you follow the template it gives you rather than trying to set up the storyboard yourself, it should work without any hassle. I know it's not a real solution, but I would do it anyway ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot souvickcse it works the way you post here. Thanks a lot 9000 for your answer. +1 to both of you.